# testing grape returns uninitialized constant V1 with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, ruby-grape

I currently have defined an auth class using grape as below:

```
module V1
  class ApiAuth < Grape::API
    resource :auth do
      desc "Creates and returns access_token if valid login"
        post ...
```

this class resides in the app/api/v1 directory. My test looks like the following:

```
class V1::ApiAuthTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end

  def setup
    @candidate = create(:candidate_with_encrypted_password)
  end

  test 'returns status 201 when logged in' do
    ...
```

When I run the test with "rake test test/api/v1/api_auth_test.rb" the test runs fine. However if I run all tests with "rake test" or "rake test test/api/v1/*" I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant V1
/Users/user/Projects/learning/test/api/v1/api_auth_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What am I doing wrong, do I have to load the V1 module in the test_helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that `V1` is not defined at the point that Ruby loads the test file. You have to load (or `require`) the relevant app code that you are testing, and that `require` must run before you can refer `V1` directly.

Yes the test helper is usually a good place to do that. You may also need to `require` the test helper file from your test if you are not already.

If you are already requiring the app code in order to test it, later, then this can be treated as a simpler problem of the namespace not existing yet. Either define it in the helper:

```
module V1
end
```

Or change your test code from the question to fully nest the namespace:

```
module V1
  class ApiAuthTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Etc.
```

Which approach to take depends on how you want to organise your dependencies. If anything else in the test file which runs at the time it is loaded depends on definitions elsewhere (e.g. `Rack::Test::Methods` has to be defined in order to `include` it), then it needs to be loaded *before* the test file references it.

You don't usually need to worry about things defined inside the `test` blocks until they are run, so you can often load the test code and then the app code in that order, and everything will work just fine. In this case it could just be the missing namespace that has caused you to need to notice load order of the files.